# How to output multiple CSS files from single JS file in Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

In my js file 'example.js' I want to import two .scss files 'example.scss' and 'example.m.scss' for desktop and mobile version of website respectively. So I need three outputs - example.js, example.scss and example.m.scss. How I can achieve it in Webpack 4?

JS file:

```
// CSS
import '../../css/example.scss';
import '../../css/mobile/example.m.scss';
```

My current Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/main_home/main_home.js',
       // ...
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/assets'),
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss|.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
        }),
        
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @MuhammadMabrouk No, I decided put mobile and desktop css to one file. For performance reason maybe not good, but what to do...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works for .scss files as well but according to this [resource](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/webpack/merge-multiple-css-into-single-file/) you could do the following with .css files (*however they state that webpack is no the best tool for that*):

The best way to merge CSS files into one independent CSS file is to use **extract-text-webpack-plugin**.

```
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

Edit **webpack.config.js** to include setup the plugin.

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle.min.css': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css/main.css'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css/local.css')
    ],
    'bundle.js': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.min.css"),
  ]
};
```

The generated **dist/bundle.min.css** is pure css file combining **src/css/main.css** and **src/css/local.css**.

```
# npm run build
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
# build for production (with minified)
./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

***NOTE***: If you follow the link above you can find the steps for **Lass** and **Less** files as well.